# Lost wallet address from 5 years ago.

Tags: lost-bitcoins

I purchased 250$ worth of bitcoin back in 2012 on coinRnr and made two transfers with coinRnr with what I bought from them too two different addresses. I was quite messed up at the time since I spent most of that money on Silkroad but do know that I had 106$ of bitcoin left that I bought and I am hoping it is still out there. I have the emails from coinRnr and Blockchain wallet that's empty and bitstamp which I can't remember my password. With the email from coinRnr that had the address they sent the bitcoin to can I find out what wallet it went to or is that not possible ?

Answer (score 1):

No, addresses are randomly generated and carry no information about what wallet they are associated with.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know one of your addresses, and have access to your Blockchain wallet, you may be able to identify which transaction you used to deposit money to Bitstamp. If you can provide your identity to Bitstamp and a deposit transaction that is linked to your account, Bitstamp may be able to help you restore your account. On the other hand, just restoring your account at Bitstamp would likely have the same effect.

If you've sent your bitcoins to another wallet or service, and only have the address to go on, you'll probably be unable to recover your bitcoins, since the address alone does not provide any information that can be used to identify the owner.